# Images won't display unless directory name begins with underscore

Tags: php, image, .htaccess

I'm setting up a gallery.  Images are inside a directory called 'gallery' on my localhost.  Same thing for for my host server (1and1).

So, the issue is that when the actual directory is named 'gallery' the images don't display.  But, when I rename the directory with an underscore such as:  _gallery the images display properly.

The code that is suppose to work is a simple straight-up html code, but no dice:

```
<div class="client-gallery">
    <img src="gallery/picture-01.jpg" />
</div>
```

So, in order for it to display the images, I have to create the directory as "_gallery" and of course the code:

```
<div class="client-gallery">
    <img src="_gallery/picture-01.jpg" />
</div>
```

I'm thinking it may be something to do with my Rewrites:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^project-details/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/ project-details.php?pn=$1 [NC,L]
Rewriterule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

I could just leave the directory as _gallery, but that doesn't let me know what the heck is going on with the file.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

The set up is your basic set up.  The files have a basic PHP include_once callers since I separated the header, footer, jscripts, etc.  Other than that...it's straight forward and frustrating I'm having a brain fart and unable to figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: Correct on the second one.  I would like to have the directory as "gallery" and the images in it to display.  But, the images only display when the directory has an underscore in front.  I can name it "tootles" and they won't display, but they would if it were "_tootles".

Comment: What happens if you temporarily disable your rewrites and try to view the image in the browser when the directory is named `gallery/`?

Comment: Ah!  Thanks, Mr. Glass.  It's something to do with my .htaccess file.  Just disabled the .htaccess by commenting all the lines out.  Going to take it line by line and see which one is the culprit.  I'll post the results shortly.  Again, thank you.  LOL, such a noob move in debugging 101.

Comment: @MrGlass So, the the culprit is the last RewriteRule:

Rewriterule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/ $1.php [NC,L]

Not sure how or why it would make it mandatory to name a directory with an underscore in order to display images.  Going to do some more digging and work on it.  The RewriteRule is necessary for the website to work with friendly URLs though...so we'll see what I come up with to make it work or just give in and use the underscore.  It's now all about the principle, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like moving the culprit line to be the first RewriteRule it fixed the issue with the directories.  Thank you everyone for helping me debug this issue!